# Export null tabels (name table and comment) of mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I have large database, I want to get an export from phpmyadmin, so that the export contains only the names of the tables(structure) without data and record.

How can i get this export? thanks

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/168595/how-to-export-mysql-schema-from-phpmyadmin/1054912

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your request is to take a dump of all tables structure without data I am not sure why you are trying out with phpmyadmin. You should be able to do it using mysqldump. Did you try mysqldump or you want to do it using phpmyadmin only ?

mysqldump -u username -p password --single-transaction database_name --no-data > database_name.dump

Comment: If you don't have shell access or database server is behind a firewall you can't use mysqldump (and that might be the reason why Hussein was looking for a phpmyadmin solution).